# Remove same records created within 5min

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is a list of transactions with errors.

Please consider same transactions (same `account_id`, `currency`, `value`, `error`, `type`, `country`) created within 5min are duplicates, and my target is to remove them in BigQuery.

i.e.
T3, T4, T5 are duplicates of T2, should all be removed and only keep T2 (the earliest created).

T6, T8 are duplicates of T5, and should only keep T5.

A little more background if you are interested:
The rationale behind is that customers tend to retry their transaction once they hit an error, but having those duplicates exaggerated the dollar value of the error occured.

My table:

```
txn_id  account_id  create_time                    currency value   error   type    country
T1      ID1         2020-12-11 15:18:19.547 UTC     AUD     60.21   Y      TYPE1    AUS
T2      ID2         2020-12-11 15:18:39.455 UTC     USD     57.91   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T3      ID2         2020-12-11 15:18:54.314 UTC     USD     57.91   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T4      ID2         2020-12-11 15:19:09.273 UTC     USD     57.91   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T5      ID2         2020-12-11 15:19:44.683 UTC     USD     57.91   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T6      ID2         2020-12-11 15:18:38.678 UTC     USD     97.17   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T8      ID2         2020-12-11 15:19:41.670 UTC     USD     97.17   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T9      ID2         2020-12-09 16:01:43.356 UTC     USD     45.00   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
```

Expected result:

```
txn_id  account_id  create_time                    currency value   error   type    country
T1      ID1        2020-12-11 15:18:19.547 UTC      AUD     60.21   Y      TYPE1    AUS
T2      ID2        2020-12-11 15:18:39.455 UTC      USD     57.91   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T6      ID2        2020-12-11 15:18:38.678 UTC      USD     97.17   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
T9      ID2        2020-12-09 16:01:43.356 UTC      USD     45.00   Y      TYPE1    NYUSA
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(create_time) over (partition by account_id order by create_time) as next_create_time
      from t
     ) t
where next_create_time is null or
      next_create_time > timestamp_add(create_time, interval 5 minute);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete records from your table then tou can use `exists` clause as follows:

```
Delete from your_table t
Where exists 
     (select 1 from your_table tt 
       Where t.account_id = tt.account_id
         And t.create_time between tt.create_time 
                               and timestamp_add(tt.create_time, interval 5 minute);
```